# Как спарсить HTML-страницу с помощью Python Grab с JQuery

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, парсер, grab

Нужно спарсить одну страницу, где нужна авторизация и разбор страницы, на которой постоянно обновляются данные с помощью Jquery. Авторизацию прохожу.
Вопрос в том, как разобрать/спарсить такую страницу? Спарсить по примеру нижеописанной страницы, к примеру элемент, с `id="speak"`

Вот учебный пример такой страницы, элементы которой, после загрузки самой страницы, изменяются c Jquery.
Я использую стандартные для grab запросы:

```
g = Grab(log_file='out.html')
g.setup(headers={'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'})
g.go('http://127.0.0.1:80/get_stats')

#получаю необходимые данные, но до изменения с Jquery
#те, которые сразу пришли с локального сервера
g.doc.select('//*[@id="speak"]')[0].text()
```

Вот учебный пример страницы:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function my_foo(){
            $.get('/test',{},function(data){
                $("#speak").empty();
                $("#speak").append(data);

            setTimeout(my_foo, 5000);
            });
        }

        $(function(){
          //jq version is 1.11
            my_foo();
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>В очереди: {{ data.0 }}</h2>
    <h2>Время ожидания: {{ data.1 }}</h2>
    <h2 id="speak">Говорят: {{ data.2 }}</h2>
    <h2>Вызов: {{ data.3 }}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью Grab не выйдет парсить динамические страницы, используйте [selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) или [Ghost](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/). Grab не может выполнить эту задачу, потому что для запуска JavaScript кода необходим движок, который этот самый код выполнит. Соответственно, нужно копать в сторону [безголовых браузеров](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser) (без интерфейса).